# How watch vue resource HTTP get data changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I need to **watch** a vue-resource HTTP get request. If found new data, I want that **push** to **v-for** loop, if found data deleted I want to **remove** that without re-render the entire **v-for** data.

### JS

```
new Vue({
    el: '#chats',

    http: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    },

    data: {
        chats: []
    },

    watch: {
        /* 
        * I need to watch the 'chats' data
        * if found new data, I want that push it
        * if found data deleted I want to remove it
        */
    },

    methods: {
        indexChats: function() {

            /* vue-resource
            * I need to watch this http get data for changes
            */
            this.$http.get('/api/chats').then((response) => {
                this.$set('chats', response.json());

            }, (response) => {
                console.log('could not fetch chats from api');
            });
        }
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.indexChats();
    }
});
```

### HTML

I want to show the chats without fully re-render the entire **v-for** loop. Just update the changes that figure out by the **watcher**.

```
<ul id="chats">
    <li v-for="chat in chats">{{ chat.message }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `track-by` attribute and use a unique identifier from your `chats` model.  When the array updates, Vue will use the existing rendered DOM to display each element instead of rendering new HTML.

```
<li v-for="chat in chats" track-by="id">{{ chat.message }}</li>
```

Existing HTML will be used to render an `<li>` if it has the same id. Then you just have to handle the array and not worry about the rendering.

You don't need `watch` to handle inserting and removing elements from that array, it is inherently monitored by Vue.  You just have to write the logic of checking if an item has been added or removed so you can update `chats` accordingly.